# Java how to use ListIterator for Queue?

Tags: java, vector, stack, queue

It was my original code.

```
Stack<Character> var = new Stack<Character>();

... add elements to stack...

for(ListIterator<Character> i = var.listIterator(); i.hasNext();){
    if(i.next() == '*'){
        i.remove();
        i.previous();
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Here, I realized Queue should be used instead, so I changed the first line into

```
Queue<Character> var = new LinkedList<Character>();
```

But, I found that there is no ListIterator for Collection.

Why only Vector has ListIterator method? Then, do I have to change the five lines in for loop if I change Stack to Queue?

Comment: Why would a `Collection` have a `ListIterator` unless it's a `List`?

Comment: I am confused - a `LinkedList` implements `List` which has an iterator

Comment: @ScaryWombat But at compile time, var is considered as Queue.

Comment: But again `Queue` has the iterator method

Comment: But LinkedList has https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)

Comment: Queue doesn't have ListIterator which gives me compile error. But I think it would be useful to have ListIterator for Queue (I deleted some comments)

Comment: @SeanHwang Not all `Queue` implementations are ordered like a `List`, which is why a `Queue` is not a `List`, and doesn't have a `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class *is* a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is why you could call [`listIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator--).

Now it seems that you want to use the [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) API, but it doesn't has a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), or any other kind of iterator that allows you to walk backwards.

So you have two choices:

1. Change your `var` variable to be type [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), since it is both a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) at the same time, which means you get both APIs.

   [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is the only built-in class implementing both.
2. Since your logic only requires you to look/remove backwards, you can change your logic to iterate backwards, instead of your current logic of iterating forward, then stepping backwards to remove previous element.

   The [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) API is an extension of the [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) API, for using a "double ended queue". A double-ended queue can be iterated backwards using the [`descendingIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator--) method.

   The advantage of [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) is that there are 4 built-in implementations, giving you more choices: [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html), [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html).

If you choose option 2, your code would be something like this:

```
Deque<Character> var = new LinkedList<>();

// add elements to queue
var.addAll(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', '*', 'C', 'D', '*', 'E'));

// remove '*' elements and immediately preceding element
for (Iterator<Character> i = var.descendingIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    if (i.next() == '*') {
        i.remove();
        i.next(); // next() when descending actually means previous queue element
        i.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(var); // prints: [A, C, E]
```

Comment: Option two made my life so much easier :) Thank you.